# I'm getting an error that says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' and i do not know how to fix it

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def trash(self, ctx, user: discord.Member):
        auth = str(os.getenv("FLIPNOTE_API"))
        url2 = f'https://api.alexflipnote.dev/trash?face={ctx.author.avatar_url_as(format="png")}&trash={user.avatar_url_as(format="png")}'
        headers = {'Authorization': auth}
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url2, headers=headers) as res:
                link = re.compile(r"(?<=<ClientResponse\()(.*)(?=\))").search(repr(res)).group(1)
                link2 = BytesIO(link)
                image = await link2.read()
                file = discord.File(image, filename="lol.png")
                await ctx.send(file=file)
```

This is the code i'm using and the error is AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
Please tell me how i can fix this i would appreciate it
this is the traceback btw:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/DayStride/cogs/fun.py", line 1461, in trashmoment
    link2 = BytesIO(link)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 71, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/DayStride/cogs/fun.py", line 1480, in trasherror
    await await ctx.send(error)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 943, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 940, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 907, in invoke
    await ctx.command.dispatch_error(ctx, exc)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 422, in dispatch_error
    await injected(cog, ctx, error)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 77, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

It says NoneType can't be used in await expression but i think the main problem is the str thing but im not sure

Comment: Please post the traceback message so we can see the full message and the failing line in context.

Comment: As an aside, `re` keeps a cache of recently used regular expressions. If you do `link = re.search(r"(?<=<ClientResponse\()(.*)(?=\))", repr(res)).group(1)` it will likely be more efficient than recompiling every time.

Comment: I have added the traceback

Comment: Your post title says "I'm getting an error that says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'", but I don't see that anywhere in the traceback you posted.

Comment: Okay, so talk me through how you intend for the code to work. You do some regex thing and get a string from the user's message, which you save as `link`. Then you want to try to create a `BytesIO` object from that string... why? And then you want to read from that stream... and this is somehow supposed to create an `image`? How?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. `link2 = BytesIO(link)` is the problem. `discord.File` wants either a file object with an image in it or a file name. I don't know what `link = re.compile(..).searhc(..)` is supposed to be getting, but its a string, not a binary image. When you try to do `BytesIO(link)` the failure is that `BytesIO` can only by a `bytes` object, not `str`. So what is `link` supposed to be? Is it a file on the local disk?

Comment: I tried to use an api that needs a token to access, in that api there is an endpoint which you need two avatars for. the returned endpoint is some stuff that i dont understand but the url that i need is how i got it from the regex but when i send it it doesnt actually show the image so i tried to convert it into bytes but i seem to struggle

Comment: link is the returned value of the res and the link that i need 
is here: 
<ClientResponse(https://api.alexflipnote.dev/trash?face=https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/670972734960042005/0df7475314580e4b21e48c967ad1feef.png?size=1024&trash=https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/670972734960042005/0df7475314580e4b21e48c967ad1feef.png?size=1024) [200 ]>......
but when i send the link it doesnt show the image

Comment: So you want to download an image and then make it into a `discord.File` so that you can send it? You could use some form of `aiohttp.request(link)` for that part, but I'm not sure the exact way to do it so this is not quite an answer.

Comment: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#client-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

```
link2 = BytesIO(link)
image = await link2.read()
```

You should check the BytesIO(link) return value,
as it seems to be a string.
Which has no "read" method.

What are you trying to do with your caode ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Called functions such as `discord.File` could be raising the error.

Comment: You could well be right, its just that OP needs to provide more context before we know.

Comment: I'm basically using an api you can see it [here](https://api.alexflipnote.dev)
and what res sends isn't what i want i want it to do i want the picture of the endpoint but i'm struggling a bit

Comment: btw i can't actually see the returned value of BytesIO(link) because it returns the error

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

```
In-memory streams
It is also possible to use a str or bytes-like object as a file for
both reading     and writing. For strings StringIO can be used like a
file opened in text mode.
BytesIO can be used like a file opened in binary mode. Both provide full
read-write capabilities with random access.


Buffered Streams
Buffered I/O streams provide a higher-level interface to an I/O device
than raw I/O does.

class io.BytesIO([initial_bytes])
A binary stream using an in-memory bytes buffer. It inherits BufferedIOBase.
The buffer is discarded when the close() method is called.

The optional argument initial_bytes is a bytes-like object that contains
initial data.
```

It looks like you give a string argument to the BytesIO(link) constructor. link seems to be a string ? But it needs some bytes, not a string.

```
>>> view = b.getbuffer()
>>> view[2:4] = b"56"
>>> b.getvalue()
```

So you have to change the argument type, or maybee use StringIO instead.
I let you chose and try this.